# ¿Como ejecuto una accion cuando hago la descarga de un archivo directa en c#?

Tags: c#, excel, descarga

Lo que estoy haciendo es una descarga de un archivo de Excel en el momento que encuentre algún registro que ya exista en la bd, este se encarga principalmente de detectarlo, no guardarlo y descargarme un Excel indicándome los registros que se repiten, el problema comienza cuando aparte de que haga eso me ejecute un modal indicándome que pues ha habido registros que no se pudieron ingresar a la bd porque estarían duplicados.

Código actual:

Código C#:

```
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "downloadError('Temp/ReportUsers" + FilesTemplate.Length + ".xlsx');", true);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ReportUsers.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
```

Código JS:

```
 function downloadError(download) {
        $.confirm({
            title: "Repetido",
            template: 'danger',
            message: 'Hay llaves repetidas',
            buttonCancel: false,
            onOk: function() {

                return;
            }
        });

        $(".modal-body").html("<div class='text-center'><label style='font-size:12px;' >Hay llaves repetidas que no se pudieron insertar.</label><br/><a href='" + download + "'>Descargar llaves</a></div>");
        $("button[data-confirm=Ok]").html("Confirmar");
    }
```

De hecho no hay la ejecución de ninguna acción, sea cual sea el motivo y no se si sea a que no hace postback cuando se hace la descarga se queda ahí la pagina, pero entonces como puedo hacer una acción extra después de la descarga.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar libreria js de terceros que se encarguen de las descargas de archivos, a lo mejor algunas de ella te brinde algun evento onComplete el cual te avise cuando la descarga se completo.

Aqui te dejo algunos enlaces variados, espero que te funcionen o por lo menos te de una idea de lo que debes hacer.

https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-plugin-for-requesting-ajax-like-file-downloads.html

https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-File-Download

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/